# Converting webform usercontrol to MVC 4 control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to convert a webform usercontrol to MVC based usercontrol.

MessageControl.ascx

```
 public abstract class Feedback : System.Web.UI.UserControl
 {
    public string Message {get;set;}
 }

 public void ShowError()
 {
   lblMessage.InnerHtml = Message;      
 }
```

So In aspx pages I can call the public method ShowError and pass the error which will be displayed in the usercontrol ascx file.

Aspx pages

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
     if(isError = true)
     {
          MessageControl1.Message = "Error Occured";
     }  
 }
```

How can I achieve the same in MVC 4.0 ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be to use the model state for strongly typed models. Another more manual way which I regularly use is to put error messages into Viewbag and then on the view check if the entry in the Viewbag exists and if it does display the error. for example (in asp.net mvc):

```
<div id="notification_error" class="invalid" <%if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(""+TempData[ "ErrorMsg" ])){ %>style="display: none;"
        <%} %>>
        <%= TempData["ErrorMsg"] %>
    </div>
```